# undefined reference to `__android_log_print'

Tags: android, java-native-interface, logging, android-ndk

What is wrong with my make file?

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := foo
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := foo.c
LOCAL_EXPORT_LDLIBS := -llog
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

foo.c

```
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <android/log.h>

#define  LOG_TAG    "foo"
#define  LOGI(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__)

void test() {
    LOGI("test");
}
```

ndk-build

```
foo.c:9: undefined reference to `__android_log_print'
```

Comment: Modify line LOCAL_EXPORT_LDLIBS := -llog to LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Try the following in your `Android.mk` file:

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib -llog
```

Comment: What is the necessary to add this? Would you Please explain in detail?

Comment: its adding an android library to the make file - and it worked for me too

Comment: the -L is unnecessary. Please accept the other answer instead.

Comment: Why is the -L unnecessary?

Comment: The -L is useful when you have subdirectories that build libraries.  Otherwise, just having -llog works fine.

Comment: The -L flag specifies an additional path that the linker should use to search for libraries. If `liblog` doesn't reside under `$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib` then it is unnecessary.

Comment: If using the new Gradle NDK integration in Android Studio 1.3, you need to add `ldLibs = ["android", "log"]` to your android.ndk options

Comment: @StephenKaiser unbelievable, I don't know how I noticed your comment, but you're THE SAVIOR

Comment: What if we are not using Android.mk's ?

Comment: @cagdas for AS 2.2, stable plugin and CMake look at my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40512650/1979756)

Answer (score 103):

You need to add

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
```

to Android.mk

Comment: correct. if there are multiple libraries, need to add this statement for each one of them (after CLEAR VARS)

Answer (score 86):

If you use Android Studio and gradle, it ignores Android.mk. Add this to your build.gradle file:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ndk {
            moduleName "your_module_name"
            ldLibs "log"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder where this is documented. I was looking for this as well.

Comment: I was getting "undefined reference to '__android_log_print'" before I have added `ldLibs`. Thanks.

Comment: Adding this fixed it for me. Just make sure to add the `ndk` part in the build.gradle inside the `app` folder instead of the one in the project folder (module name).

Comment: As of  Gradle 2.5 use 'ldLibs += "log"' slight syntax change

Comment: this did NOT work for me.  this is what I had to do: `ldLibs.addAll(["android", "log"])`

Comment: Using the latest versions of everything as of 21-Jun-2016, the `ldLibs "log"` line fails for me with `Cause: org.gradle.api.internal.ExtensibleDynamicObject`. The `ldLibs.addAll` statement in the above comment works. I also tried `+=`, but that failed in a different way.

Answer (score 36):

For Android Studio 2.2 and tools.build:gradle:2.2.0 using CMake add or edit row in CMakeLists.txt:

```
target_link_libraries(<your_library_name> 
                      android 
                      log)
```

Thats connecting log library to yours.

Answer (score 16):

If you upgrade to Android Studio 2.1, above answers do not work, need use ldLibs.add() to load the lib as below:

```
android.ndk {
    moduleName = "[the_module_name]"
    ldLibs.addAll(['android', 'log'])
}
```

Comment: best modern (late 2017) answer

Answer (score 12):

In case the project you are working on has the following characteristics that differ from other 'standard' answers:

- Not using Android Studio
- Not using gradle and the integrated CMake
- No Android.mk or Application.mk used at all for build
- Using CMake and the toolchain directly (maybe your project is Qt based and without using QtCreator neither)

The following [target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/command/target_link_libraries.html) usage makes it:

```
    find_library(ANDROID_LOG_LIB log)
    target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME} ${ANDROID_LOG_LIB})
```

Being `TARGET_NAME`the name of the target to build (having set it up before with `add_library` or `add_executable`).

`find_library` is equally important as well as setting up the toolchain properly (use the toolchain provided by Android SDK at `ANDROID_SDK_HOME/cmake/<version>/android.toolchain.cmake` so it sets up `CMAKE_SYSROOT`which is used by `find_` commands).

Comment: Only solution that helped me! Thanks a ton, I would extend it by a test if the library was found for better feedback to the developer as here https://stackoverflow.com/a/37868829/10030695

Answer (score 7):

We can link a shared library in Android in 3 ways.
In below 3 cases, the lines mentioned should be added in `Android.mk`

So here are the three ways.

```
1. LOCAL_LDLIBS way
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
```

For some reason if 1 doesnt work(it did not work for me), You can try below 2 ways

```
2. LOCAL_LDFLAGS way
LOCAL_LDFLAGS := -llog

3. LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES way
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += liblog
```

Of course you also need to include `#include <android/log.h>`  in your C/H file.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you do need to add: `LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog` as the other answers/comments have specified, however the original question did not specify if he use the jni library as: `LOCAL_JNI_SHARED_LIBRARIES` or as `LOCAL_REQUIRED_MODULES`.

I can pretty much say for sure that he has it used it as: `LOCAL_REQUIRED_MODULES` because of the `LOCAL_EXPORT_LDLIBS := -llog` in the question... unless that was added after an edit.

If you use `LOCAL_REQUIRED_MODULES` the shared library is installed in /system/lib instead of into the apk, because it is a required module. Therefore you will need to add `LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib -llog` instead of just `LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog` so that when the build system is building & linking the jni shared library, it will have the `-llog` definitions in the correct place, available to be built under `$OUT/root/system/lib`. Otherwise you will continue to get the same answer, even if you only add `LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog`.

So, those who commented that the `-L` is not needed, and the other answer was correct, they were actually incorrect in this situation.

Comment: Thank you for actually explaining what's going on!

Answer (score 4):

In lieu with

> If using the new Gradle NDK integration in Android Studio 1.3, you need to add ldLibs = ["android", "log"] to your android.ndk options – Stephen Kaiser Sep 24 at 4:20

use `ldLibs.addAll(["android", "log"])` for the experimental plugin

Answer (score 4):

for the case who use `CMakeLists.txt` to make

```
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path 'src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt'
        }
    }
```

just add **-llog** into target_link_libraries:

```
target_link_libraries(<your_library_name> -llog)
```

the env I used are :

gradle-6.5-all.zip

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1'

Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7621141, built on August 8, 2021

Comment: After scouring for hours, found the ONLY solution (your post) to make it work for CMakeLists.txt (all existing sources are for Android.mk). Added "target_link_libraries(native-lib -llog)" to CMakeLists.txt and PRESTO! I'm crying. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Add

```
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES:= \
        libbinder                       \
        liblog                          \
```

to Android.mk

Comment: Why? Please explain why this answer should work for the asker.

Answer (score 2):

-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-llog" helps me

Answer (score 2):

TO build with Android.bp, follow the below solution:

In this -**android_log_print** is defined in NDK, so for this, there is already a library is available. Use "**liblog**" library using **shared_libs** tag, take reference of the below code:

```
target: {
        android: {
            cppflags: [
                "-g",
                "-DUSE_LIBLOG",
            ],
            shared_libs: ["liblog"], // can use other dependency if required.
        },
        darwin: {
            enabled: false,
        },
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

This helped for me:

Android.mk

```
    LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := nativeDemo
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the android studio version 2.2 and higher, there is inbuilt support for CPP when you create a new project. Also, the liblog.so is included by default. Nothing to be done apart from including the header file (android/log.h).

Checkout app/CMakeLists.txt that is created by the studio when we create new android studio project. We can see that the find_library() block and target_link_libraries() block for loglib are already present.

Also, pay attention towards the function syntax. It should be:

> **__android_log_print (int priority, const char *tag, const char *fmt,...);**

In my case, I had left out tag parameter and ended up spending good 3 days in figuring it out.

More about CMake: [Add C and C++ Code to Your Project](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html)

Answer (score 0):

add
`LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES:= liblog`
to Android.mk can solve my isuue.
This is because the `__android_log_print` is defined in libLog