# How to build CMakeLists the right way?

Tags: c++, cmake, android-ndk, linker

I have the following issue: I have two different sets of files (main and an additional one), that I would like to keep separate. So, I have one set of files (main), that I configure this way:

```
set(libplayersource
        ....
        )

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
        libplayer

        # Sets the library as a shared library.
        SHARED

        # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
        ${libplayersource})
```

Then I have second set of files (additional), that I configure this way:

```
set(codec_source
        ...)

add_library(libcodec SHARED ${codec_source})
```

Eventually, I need to link these two sets of files:

```
target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
        libplayer
        libcodec)
```

And after this configuration, I also need to include `log` lib in order to make it work. Firstly, I need to find this `log` lib, and then include it in my native lib.

```
find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
        log-lib

        # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
        # you want CMake to locate.
        log)
```

Also, I should to edit `target_link_libraries` to include `log` lib:

```
target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
        libplayer
        libcodec
        ${log-lib})
```

All is fine if you are going to use this `log` lib in `libplayer`, but if you are going to use it in `libcodec` set, you'll get this error:

> undefined reference to `__android_log_print'
>
> clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

It is means that the linker doesn't see the implementation of this method.

I found this answer on SO:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47803975/5709159

and in order to solve the issue, I have added to my `CMakeLists` file this line:

```
target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
        libcodec
        android
        ${log-lib}
        )
```

---

Main CMake file implementation:

```
...
#Main module
set(libplayersource
        ....
        )

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
        libplayer

        # Sets the library as a shared library.
        SHARED

        # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
        ${libplayersource})

#Additional module
set(codec_source
        ...)

add_library(libcodec SHARED ${codec_source})

#Log lib
find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
        log-lib

        # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
        # you want CMake to locate.
        log)

#Linking

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
        libcodec
        ${log-lib}
        )

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
        libplayer
        libcodec
        ${log-lib})
...
```

So, I need to mention `log` lib in both of libraries.

**Question is** - Why doesn't the linker see `log` lib in `libcodec`? Why do I have to add the additional block?

```
target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
        libcodec
        ${log-lib}
        )
```

to make `log` lib visible for linker in `libcodec`?

**P.S** In Visual Studio, if you have main project A and two libs B and C,  you include these B and C libs in A, and that is it; everyone knows about everyone. I can call methods in B from C and so on. In order to call a B method from C, I don't need to include C in B. It is enough that both of these libs are included in A as a main project...

If I missed something in the question, feel free to ask.

Comment: Because `libcodec` is compiled and linked separately from the rest of the program. Why should CMake guess that for you?

Comment: @Botje edited my question, added P.S block

Comment: Are you absolutely sure Visual Studio does this for *static* libraries (`.lib`s) _AND_ *shared* libraries (DLLs)? I would expect the shared situation to fail similarly in VS.

Comment: @Botje do you mean one of libs should be static and other one shared? I am not sure, but if it will be two of them static (.lib) , so they can to speak each to other

Comment: They do not 'speak to each other'. The compiler probably generates static libraries (`.lib` files) with unmet symbol references. It is only when you link everything together in an executable or another shared library that the unmet symbols are resolved. If you make `libplayer` and `libcodec` STATIC in your CMakeLists.txt you will see the same result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your `libcodec` uses the implementations defined in `log-lib`, you **must** link `log-lib` to `libcodec` explicitly. This call:

```
target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
        libplayer
        libcodec
        ${log-lib})
```

links `libcodec` and `log-lib` to `libplayer`, it **does not** link `log-lib` to `libcodec`. It implies this dependency graph:

```
        libplayer
        /       \
  libcodec     log-lib
```

The first argument to the `target_link_libraries()` call is the "linked-to" library, and all the following targets are **linked to** the first. Thus, you need to link `log-lib` to `libcodec`, like this:

```
target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
        libcodec
        ${log-lib}
        )
```

Now, `libcodec` will know about the implementation defined in `log-lib`, implying the dependency graph here:

```
        libplayer
        /       \
  libcodec     log-lib
     /
log-lib
```

---

You *can* make this cleaner though. We can remove the direct link between `libplayer` and `log-lib`, and allow the `log-lib` implementation **propagate** through `libcodec` to `libplayer`.

```
target_link_libraries(libcodec PUBLIC
        ${log-lib}
        )

target_link_libraries(libplayer PRIVATE
        libcodec
        )
```

This will simplify the dependency graph to the following:

```
        libplayer
        /
  libcodec
     /
log-lib
```

See [this](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html#libraries-for-a-target-and-or-its-dependents) section in the CMake documentation for how and when to use the `PUBLIC` and `PRIVATE` keywords when linking.

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly this approach is actually right way for such implementation, right?

Comment: Yes, however, it would seem you can simplify this a bit. If `libplayer` depends on `libcodec`, and `libcodec` depends on `log-lib`, you link `log-lib` *only* to `libcodec`, and it will be **inhereted** by `libplayer` through `libcodec`.

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko I expanded my answer to show this simplification. Hope this is helpful!